# User level restrictions on ethereum

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, restrictions

I have two queries related to ethereum. I am trying to do a proof of concept that required multiple users to have access to a blockchain node.

(1). Can I have like a million user accounts on Ethereum's Node. Or does ethereum has restriction in the number of accounts.

(2). I want to have user level restrictions in place. So, for instance there are two customers transacting with few other customers. Each of the customers should see his own transaction. Simply said.

For instance, both the below transactions happen on a blockchain node.
A->B 5 USD
C->D 10 USD

A and B should only see 5 USD transaction on their UI.
C and D should only see 10 USD transaction on their UI.
Bank should see both the transactions.

Is the above possible on ethereum or do we have some restrictions on above.

Responses are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In the public Ethereum network:

**Q1:** You can have data about as many accounts as you require. Someone pays the gas cost of all state commits. This data is on all verifier nodes, so generally-speaking, everyone has a copy.

**Q2:** It's possible to design smart contracts to enforce these sorts of rules, but one should keep in mind that all information on the chain is visible to a determined adversary even if the contract(s) is designed to restrict access. Since all nodes verify all transactions, it follows that all data is visible to all nodes.

There are some variants of Ethereum that apply different approaches to verification and confidentiality.

[Different between various blockchain protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690983/different-between-various-blockchain-protocols)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for response. So, in my scenario I am just keeping one node with the bank and maintaining multiple accounts of the customers on that node. So can I put user level restrictions for each use whereby each customer can see his/her transactions whereas the bank can see all transactions since bank has a node.

Comment: Trying not to mislead. I'm sensing confusion about topology. Are you thinking of the public Ethereum network, or a private chain? All data is on all nodes at all times.

Comment: Private Ethereum. Bank runs one node with multiple customer accounts maintained on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,You can do this by writing some logic which will restrict customer to see some certain transaction and other stuff. this can only be done in front end application. Ethereum is permission-less block chain network which means that every one in network can see all the data. From front end we can stop users but keep in mind still they can view all the transaction or data from Ethereum client console like GETH.
Note:it is not best use case for Ethereum you can use fabric for it.